# Audio: Change Volume of samples in byte array

Tags: java, audio, arrays, volume, javasound

I'm reading a wav-file to a byte array using [this method (shown below)](http://snippi.com/s/ndi3f4x). Now that I have it stored inside my byte array, I want to change the sounds volume.

```
private byte[] getAudioFileData(final String filePath) {
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final File file = new File(filePath);
    final AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int c;
    while ((c = audioInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        baout.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    audioInputStream.close();
    baout.close();
    data = baout.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

**Edit:** Per request some info on the audio format:

> PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian

From physics-class I remembered that you can change the amplitude of a sine-wave by multiplying the sine-value with a number between 0 and 1.

**Edit: Updated code for 16-bit samples:**

```
private byte[] adjustVolume(byte[] audioSamples, double volume) {
    byte[] array = new byte[audioSamples.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2) {
        // convert byte pair to int
        int audioSample = (int) ((audioSamples[i+1] & 0xff) << 8) | (audioSamples[i] & 0xff);

        audioSample = (int) (audioSample * volume);

        // convert back
        array[i] = (byte) audioSample;
        array[i+1] = (byte) (audioSample >> 8);

    }
    return array;
}
```

The sound is heavily distorted if I multiply `audioSample` with `volume`. If I don't and compare both arrays with `Arrays.compare(array, audioSample)` I can conclude that the byte-array is being converted correctly to int and the other way around.

Can anybody help me out? What am I getting wrong here? Thank you! :)

Comment: You might get better answers on dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Report `audioInputStream.getFormat()`.

Comment: @egrunin Thank you! Can I just copy & paste it there or what are the rules for moving topics?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for your tips. `audioInputStream.getFormat()` says: PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian

Comment: Uh-huh.  See the [answer by @johusman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14486022/418556).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure you're reading 8-bit mono audio? Otherwise one byte does not equal one sample, and you cannot just scale each byte. E.g. if it is 16-bit data you have to parse every pair of bytes as a 16-bit integer, scale that, and then write it back as two bytes.

Comment: Thank you. My audio has a sample size of 16 bits. I'm going to read up on how to convert my byte array properly and give you my feedback once I managed to do that.

Comment: Hey. :) I've finally managed to correctly convert my byte array to int and back. However, my sound is even more heavily distorted than before if I multiply my samples with `volume`. I've updated the code in the question. Could you have a look? That would be great. Thank you! :)

Comment: Just gave it a quick glance, but I suspect you aren't dealing properly with negative values (you convert to an `int`, which is 32-bit, maybe you could use a `short`?). Remember that java's signed integers are two's complement.

Answer (score 10):

Problem in int type, size of int in java is 4 bytes and the sample size is 2 bytes

This worked code:

```
private byte[] adjustVolume(byte[] audioSamples, float volume) {
        byte[] array = new byte[audioSamples.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2) {
            // convert byte pair to int
            short buf1 = audioSamples[i+1];
            short buf2 = audioSamples[i];

            buf1 = (short) ((buf1 & 0xff) << 8);
            buf2 = (short) (buf2 & 0xff);

            short res= (short) (buf1 | buf2);
            res = (short) (res * volume);

            // convert back
            array[i] = (byte) res;
            array[i+1] = (byte) (res >> 8);

        }
        return array;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to also control stereo volume ?

Comment: YES and quite easily once you know PCM is 16-bit LL RR LL RR LL RR LL (where each character is 1 byte) so I just increment i by 4 and reuse your code.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by Rodion was a good starting point, but it not sufficient to give good results.

It introduced overflows and was not fast enough for real-time audio on Android.

### TL;DR: My improved solution involving a LUT and gain compression

```
private static int N_SHORTS = 0xffff;
private static final short[] VOLUME_NORM_LUT = new short[N_SHORTS];
private static int MAX_NEGATIVE_AMPLITUDE = 0x8000;

static {
    precomputeVolumeNormLUT();
}    

private static void normalizeVolume(byte[] audioSamples, int start, int len) {
    for (int i = start; i < start+len; i+=2) {
        // convert byte pair to int
        short s1 = audioSamples[i+1];
        short s2 = audioSamples[i];

        s1 = (short) ((s1 & 0xff) << 8);
        s2 = (short) (s2 & 0xff);

        short res = (short) (s1 | s2);

        res = VOLUME_NORM_LUT[res+MAX_NEGATIVE_AMPLITUDE];
        audioSamples[i] = (byte) res;
        audioSamples[i+1] = (byte) (res >> 8);
    }
}

private static void precomputeVolumeNormLUT() {
    for(int s=0; s<N_SHORTS; s++) {
        double v = s-MAX_NEGATIVE_AMPLITUDE;
        double sign = Math.signum(v);
        // Non-linear volume boost function
        // fitted exponential through (0,0), (10000, 25000), (32767, 32767)
        VOLUME_NORM_LUT[s]=(short)(sign*(1.240769e-22 - (-4.66022/0.0001408133)*
                           (1 - Math.exp(-0.0001408133*v*sign))));
    }
}
```

This works very well, boosts audio nicely, does not have a problem with clipping and can run real-time on Android.

### How I got there

My task was to wrap a proprietary closed-source TTS engine (supplied by customer) to make it work as a standard Android TextToSpeechService. The customer was complaining about the volume being too low, even though the stream volume was set to highest.

I had to find a way to boost the volume in Java in real-time while avoiding clipping and distortion.

There were **two problems** with Rodion's solution:

1. the code was running a bit **too slow** for real-time operation on a phone (float is slow)
2. it doesn't prevent **overflow**, which may cause bad and noticeable artifacts

I came to this solution:

**Computation speed** can be improved by trading RAM for CPU and using a look-up-table (LUT), i.e. pre-computing the volume-boost function value for every input short value out there.

**This way you sacrifice 128K of RAM but get rid of the floating point and multiplication during sound processing completely, which in my case was a win.**

**As for the overflow**, there are two ways around this. The ugly one is to simply replace the values outside of the short range with Short.MIN_VALUE or Short.MAX_VALUE respectively. It does not prevent clipping, but at least it does not overflow and the artifacts are way less disturbing.

But I found a better way, which is to **apply a non-linear boost** (also called gain compression). You can use an exponential function and instead of just pre-computing a multiplication LUT, you can pre-compute non-linear boost. Actually, the function plays very well with the LUT and any similar function can be pre-computed this way.

The best way to find a good boost function and optimal parameters for the function is to experiment with different functions for a while, a simple but good tool is https://mycurvefit.com/

One of the functions seemed promising, I just had to make a small modification to make negative values work in a symmetrical fashion.

[image]

After playing with some parameters, I came to the conclusion that I'll get good results if the function passes through [0,0], [10000, 25000] and [32767, 32767].

I needed quite a big volume boost, you may want to be more subtle.

MyCurveFit gave me this set of parameters:
y<sub>0</sub> = 1.240769e-22, v<sub>0</sub> = -4.66022, k = 0.0001408133

The final boost function to be pre-computed in the LUT looks like this:

[image: Volume boost function plot]

**Disclaimer: I'm not a DSP expert and I was warned that a boost like this is not suitable for Hi-Fi music and such, because it introduces changes in timbre, harmonics and other subtle artifacts. But it's fast and worked very well for my purpose and I think it will be acceptable for many uses involving speech and Lo-Fi stuff in general.**

Comment: Hi @jan-hadáček this code is awesome, but i'm having a little bit of trouble with it. 
On this line im getting an outofbounds
res = VOLUME_NORM_LUT[res+MAX_NEGATIVE_AMPLITUDE];

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues same, I changed it to:
res = VOLUME_NORM_LUT[Math.min(res + MAX_NEGATIVE_AMPLITUDE, N_SHORTS - 1)];

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that one byte is one sample? In this format specification  it looks like a sample has 2 byttes. And do not forget to let the header unchanged.

[WAVE PCM soundfile format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've updated my code in the question, but it's still not working. :(